# (ubuntu phone) is anyone planing on making a messenger for xmpp

Tags: ubuntu-touch, empathy, phone, pidgin, xmpp

Is anyone planing on making a messenger for Ubuntu phone which can handle xmpp (excluding webapps because there is no point of using it if it cant notify you that you have a message) I would really like seeing something like pidgin or empathy on ubuntu phone

Answer (score 0):

There are **[Loqui.im](http://loqui.im)** which support XMPP for FirefoxOS and Ubuntu Touch (and Tizen).

Unfortunately the Ubuntu Touch version doesn't seems [to be actively maintained](https://github.com/loqui/im/tree/ubuntu-touch), you may try to submit an issue on GitHub about this.